# Como fazer uma lista das iterações recursivas - Python

Tags: python, recursão, stack

Estou implementando uma torre de hanoi em python e preciso de um log de todas as jogadas. Poderia ser uma lista com os estados das 3 pilhas. Mas quando tento usar a função append para essa lista/log, o resultado é o último estado do jogo repetido pelo número de iterações. O que estou fazendo de errado?

```
pino1 = [3, 2, 1]
pino2 = []
pino3 = []
pinos = []

def moveTorre(altura, origem, destino, aux):
    if (altura > 0):
        moveTorre(altura-1, origem, aux, destino)
        moveDisk(origem, destino, altura)
        moveTorre(altura-1, aux, destino, origem)


def moveDisk(origem, destino, altura):
    global pino1
    global pino2
    global pino3
    global pinos
    destino.append(altura)
    origem.pop()
    pinos.append(pino1)
    pinos.append(pino2)
    pinos.append(pino3)
    print(pino1)
    print(pino2)
    print(pino3)
    print(pinos)


while (pino1 or pino2):
    moveTorre(3, pino1, pino3, pino2)
```

Comment: O que é o argumento `aux`?

Comment: É o pino auxiliar da torre de hanoi. O primeiro é o de origem - pino1, o terceiro é o destino - pino3, e o do meio chamei de auxiliar - pino2. Implementei eles como listas.

Comment: tente printar, depois só subistuir pelo codigo de log

Comment: O print funciona direito, mas usando o append ele substitui as entradas anteriores pela atual. Ele faz isso em todas as iterações.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

você não quer que repita os numeros mas mostre todas a interações no final?

> ele muda os valores das outras lista por conta que estão referenciada, para acabar com esse problema é só utilizar o operador de fatia `[:]` por exemplo abaixo `pinos.append(pino1[:])`

```
pino1 = [3, 2, 1]
pino2 = []
pino3 = []
pinos = []


def moveTorre(altura, origem, destino, aux):
    if altura > 0:
        moveTorre(altura-1, origem, aux, destino)
        moveDisk(origem, destino, altura)
        moveTorre(altura-1, aux, destino, origem)


def moveDisk(origem, destino, altura):
    global pino1
    global pino2
    global pino3
    global pinos
    destino.append(altura)
    origem.pop()
    pinos.append(pino1[:])
    pinos.append(pino2[:])
    pinos.append(pino3[:])
    print(pino1)
    print(pino2)
    print(pino3)
    print(pinos)


while pino1 or pino2:
    moveTorre(3, pino1, pino3, pino2)
```

Comment: Era o segundo caso. Funcionou. Muito obrigada!

Comment: nada, e não esqueça de marcar todas as repostas que foram uteis e relevantes S2